# talking between python tcp server and a c++ client

Tags: c++, python, networking, sockets, winsock

I am having an issue trying to communicate between a python TCP server and a c++ TCP client.
After the first call, which works fine, the subsequent calls cause issues.

As far as WinSock is concerned, the send() function worked properly, it returns the proper length and WSAGetLastError() does not return anything of significance.

However, when watching the packets using wireshark,   i notice that the first call sends two packets,  a PSH,ACK with all of the data in it, and an ACK right after, but the subsequent calls, which don't work, only send the PSH,ACK packet, and not a subsequent ACK packet

the receiving computers wireshark corroborates this, and the python server does nothing, it doesnt have any data coming out of the socket, and i cannot debug deeper, since socket is a native class

when i run a c++ client and a c++ server (a hacked replica of what the python one would do), the client faithfully sends both the PSH,ACk and ACK packets the whole time, even after the first call.

Is the winsock send function supposed to always send a PSH,ACK and an ACK?
If so, why would it do so when connected to my C++ server and not the python server?
Has anyone had any issues similar to this?

Comment: In either version of the server are you seeing an ack sent from the server?  You mention the client sending an ack that shouldn't happen unless you are getting something from the server.  Are you sure the python app is behaving?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> client sends a PSH,ACK and then the
>   server sends a PSH,ACK and a
>   FIN,PSH,ACK

There is a FIN, so could it be that the Python version of your server is closing the connection immediately after the initial read?

If you are not explicitly closing the server's socket, it's probable that the server's remote socket variable is going out of scope, thus closing it (and that this bug is not present in your C++ version)?

Assuming that this is the case, I can cause a very similar TCP sequence with this code for the server:

```
# server.py
import socket
from time import sleep

def f(s):
        r,a = s.accept()
        print r.recv(100)

s = socket.socket()
s.bind(('localhost',1234))
s.listen(1)

f(s)
# wait around a bit for the client to send it's second packet
sleep(10)
```

and this for the client:

```
# client.py
import socket
from time import sleep

s = socket.socket()
s.connect(('localhost',1234))

s.send('hello 1')
# wait around for a while so that the socket in server.py goes out of scope
sleep(5)
s.send('hello 2')
```

Start your packet sniffer, then run server.py and then, client.py. Here is the outout of `tcpdump -A -i lo`, which matches your observations:

```
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on lo, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 96 bytes
12:42:37.683710 IP localhost:33491 > localhost.1234: S 1129726741:1129726741(0) win 32792 <mss 16396,sackOK,timestamp 640881101 0,nop,wscale 7>
E..<R.@.@...............CVC.........I|....@....
&3..........
12:42:37.684049 IP localhost.1234 > localhost:33491: S 1128039653:1128039653(0) ack 1129726742 win 32768 <mss 16396,sackOK,timestamp 640881101 640881101,nop,wscale 7>
E..<..@.@.<.............C<..CVC.....Ia....@....
&3..&3......
12:42:37.684087 IP localhost:33491 > localhost.1234: . ack 1 win 257 <nop,nop,timestamp 640881102 640881101>
E..4R.@.@...............CVC.C<......1......
&3..&3..
12:42:37.684220 IP localhost:33491 > localhost.1234: P 1:8(7) ack 1 win 257 <nop,nop,timestamp 640881102 640881101>
E..;R.@.@...............CVC.C<......./.....
&3..&3..hello 1
12:42:37.684271 IP localhost.1234 > localhost:33491: . ack 8 win 256 <nop,nop,timestamp 640881102 640881102>
E..4.(@.@...............C<..CVC.....1}.....
&3..&3..
12:42:37.684755 IP localhost.1234 > localhost:33491: F 1:1(0) ack 8 win 256 <nop,nop,timestamp 640881103 640881102>
E..4.)@.@...............C<..CVC.....1{.....
&3..&3..
12:42:37.685639 IP localhost:33491 > localhost.1234: . ack 2 win 257 <nop,nop,timestamp 640881104 640881103>
E..4R.@.@...............CVC.C<......1x.....
&3..&3..
12:42:42.683367 IP localhost:33491 > localhost.1234: P 8:15(7) ack 2 win 257 <nop,nop,timestamp 640886103 640881103>
E..;R.@.@...............CVC.C<......./.....
&3%W&3..hello 2
12:42:42.683401 IP localhost.1234 > localhost:33491: R 1128039655:1128039655(0) win 0
E..(..@.@.<.............C<......P...b...

9 packets captured
27 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

Comment: that is most certainly the problem
im using the xmlrpc server as my python server, which apparently is a single serving entity?

Answer (score 1):

What size of packets do you send?

If they are small - may be [Nagle's Algorith & Delayed ACK Algorithm](http://www.stuartcheshire.org/papers/NagleDelayedAck/) is your headache? From what you described think Delayed ACK is involved...

Comment: i told wireshark to view everything being sent back by the server as well,  and i have found that for the first send/receive, the client sends a PSH,ACK and then the server sends a PSH,ACK and a FIN,PSH,ACK back, to which my client responds with a PSH,ACK, 

then for the second call, i send my first PSH,ACK, and the server responsd with a RST

im getting a connection reset request, which occurs when the server is not getting ACKs?   

could this be a result of the lack of double buffering?